# How can i get the errors of each iteration using fsolve to determine the root of a polynomial?

Tags: python, list, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I want to have all the errors obtained from each iteration using the fsolve function to obtain the root. To be more precise, I need to plot a graph of errors as a function of the iteration.

`root = fsolve(build_function,start_value,xtol = tolerance,maxfev= max_interations)`

Comment: Just log the arguments and function value in `build_function`. Or hack the code of `fsolve` to implement an observer facility.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a good practice what I will sugest, but it works.

You can define a global variable inside your "build_function" that will constantly stores the variable values for each iteration of the solver.

For example, you can try something like this:

```
a = []

def func(x):
    global a
    a.append(x)
    return x**2 - 5 

x0 = 1500

resp = optimize.root(func, x0)

print(a)
```